# Как правильно удалить часть функционала авторизации в laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Подскажите как правильно удалить часть функционала например:
Восстановления пароля, Подтверждения почты в laravel

Сами контролеры удалил но ошибка выходит
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController] does not exist.

Ошибка что где то видимо машруты надо удалить.

а из всего вижу только Auth::routes();

захожу в него и не пойму

```
    /**
 * Register the typical authentication routes for an application.
 *
 * @param  array  $options
 * @return void
 */
public static function routes(array $options = [])
{
    if (! array_key_exists(UiServiceProvider::class, static::$app->getLoadedProviders())) {
        throw new LogicException('Please install the laravel/ui package in order to use the Auth::routes() method.');
    }

    static::$app->make('router')->auth($options);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855619/how-to-remove-auth-in-laravel-php-artisan

Answer (score 0):

`Auth::routes()` генерирует все роуты (логин, регистрация, смена пароля и тд.)
Если хотите убрать какой-нибудь из них, то вам нужно явно указать какие роуты вы хотите вместо этой 'пачки'.

Вот [тут](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php) в методе `auth` можете посмотреть все эти роуты